# CSS Selector for a Child Element

Tags: css

Trying to find the `CSS` selector for this , but not able to succeed.

I need Span which has Class `rtIn` Where its Parent `UL` must be Child of `li`

I tried this but its applying on every node

```
.rtLI > ul > li > div > Span.rtIn {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

---

```
<ul class="rtUL">
    <li class="rtLI">
        <div class="rtTop">
            <span class="rtSp">Parent</span>
            <span class="rtMinus"></span>
           <span class="rtIn"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="rtUL">
            <li class="rtLI rtLast">
                <div class="rtBot">
                    <span class="rtSp"></span>
                    <span class="rtIn">Child</span>// i required this Span
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="rtLI">
        <div class="rtMid">
            <span class="rtSp"></span>
            <span class="rtIn">Child</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="rtLI rtLast">
        <div class="rtBot">
            <span class="rtSp"></span>
            <span class="rtIn">Child</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

any corrections ?

here is the output in fireFox and Chrome

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me  - http://jsfiddle.net/goqjbeo6/

Comment: @MaryMelody here Actual Generate Code http://jsfiddle.net/blackcrown/w4fpc8Le/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rtLI > ul > li > div > Span.rtIn {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="rtUL">
     <li class="rtLI">
       <div class="rtTop">
        <span class="rtSp"></span>
         <span class="rtMinus"></span>
          <span class="rtIn"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="rtUL">
         <li class="rtLI rtLast">
           <div class="rtBot">
             <span class="rtSp"></span>
             <span class="rtIn"></span>// i required this Span
           </div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="rtLI">
        <div class="rtMid">
         <span class="rtSp"></span>
         <span class="rtIn"></span>
        </div>
       </li>
      <li class="rtLI rtLast">
       <div class="rtBot">
         <span class="rtSp"></span>
         <span class="rtIn"></span>
        </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

The selector is working!

You had an **HTML syntax error** y your `HTML` code:

You had:

```
   span class="rtIn"></span>
```

And should be:

```
   <span class="rtIn"></span>
```

Google Chrome is getting the CSS style:

[image: Google Chrome Inspector snapshot]

Comment: Html Snippet is auto-generated, this must be a typo error. i tried it its Not working

Comment: I ahve attached a Google Chrome Inspector screenshot

Answer (score 0):

here is Actual Selector For This

```
.rtLI > ul > li > ul > li.rtLI > div > Span.rtIn {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
}
```

*JSFiddl*e : http://jsfiddle.net/blackcrown/w4fpc8Le/3/

this Answer Can be improvised , if Span is on N Depth ,then its not a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I see this has already been answered but just thought I'd throw this out there...

You could probably just use nth-child pseudo-selector instead of using classes on every container.

Chris Coyiers site www.css-tricks.com has very useful info on how it works:

http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/